# PHP web application Crash (?) on Mochahost

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I've recently created a web application using PHP, Javascript, HTML, jQuery, jQuery-ui, dataTables, and a few other less relevant PHP and javascript libraries. I have been testing the application on a Wamp server and haven't had any problems with the app aside from usual debugging etc. However, I recently deployed the application to an Apache server on mochahost, and accessing pages that have dataTables on them causes the application to crash the domain for several hours. -- Starts throwing '406 Not Acceptable' errors

I contacted Mochahost's support, and they said "it looks like an application crash, sorry we don't provide developer support. you need to review your code".  However, I haven't been having this problem at all on my local Wamp server, and their cPanel doesn't provide any logs of what's going wrong. So, I'm really looking for advice on how to solve this problem.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. -- (I would post relevant code, but the app is enormous. I wouldn't know where to start)

Comment: It's going to be pretty tough to troubleshoot without some code. Sometimes, you can take a specific page, rip out all the code, and start adding things back a piece at a time until you add the part that breaks it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice by the way jwatts. ultimately that is how I solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out the problem. I was storing session information for user login purposes, and dataTables "bStateSave : true" to keep track of individual user settings for the data tables.

The problem came up when the datatables were writing cookies to the browser. it was overwriting, or changing session values that were being used for security, thus locking up the domain until the session expired (or until I deleted the cookie).

I'm still fairly new to web development, so I apologize if this is a noobish issue. -.-